Matlab Warning: Equation is badly conditioned. Remove repeated data points or try centering and scaling
I have a data set, FR. I am trying to plot the confidence levels for the same but I am encountering a warning message :"Warning: Equation is badly conditioned. Remove repeated data points or try centering and scaling.". I don't know what is the issue as well as how to solve it. Any kind of help will be very useful. I am getting a graph like this (as shown below) but I think this enter image description here
%Create fit and confidence interval
 FitVec = fit(freq_tl,T121,'poly9')
 pRvecConf = predint(FitVec,freq_tl,0.95,'observation','off');
 
 %get the fitting values
 fitY=feval(FitVec,freq_tl);
 %multiply the confidence interval with sqrt(xVec(i)).^2 .*xVec'
 ci=(fitY-pRvecConf(:,1));
 %get the weighted confidence interval
 Conf_new=[fitY-ci,fitY+ci];
 %Plot
 figure
 plot(FitVec,freq_tl,T121) 
 hold on
 plot(freq_tl,Conf_new,'m--')
 legend('Data','Fitted curve','Confidence','Location','se')
 xlabel('Length')
 ylabel('Strength')



If you delete the peak and fit a polynomial to the baseline then you might stand a chance of having a problem that it can solve, but there is no way it can hope to fit a sharp peak like that. Try fitting a baseline polynomial curve to 100-750 and 1250-4500 then use that baseline to isolate your peak (and use the lowest order you can get a decent fit with). It also helps to have a decent model of a theoretical ideal peak for a peak fitting code to use.

Data would also be nice ;)
